# Draw GreatCircle using PathOverlay by OSMdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

Can anyone, help me draw a circle or rather precisely an Arc with a given center point (GeoPoint) and the start and end points as well. So basically, it should help me draw a sector with given center point along with start and end points. I'm planning to use PathOverlay as my baseclass from OSMdroid, so that it would be easier for me to remove or add.

I understand the greatCircle provided in PathOverlay of OSMdroid, but not quit sure how to make use of it, I was wondering if any sample example be provided. Also How would I set the center of this GreatCircle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a PathOverlay to draw filled polygons: as you noticed, this doesn't work properly when portions of the polygon are outside the screen. 
for filled polygons, use an [OSMBonusPack Polygon](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/Polygon.java).

For setting the points of your arc, there is no ready-to-use API currently.

Comment: But doesn't this overlay use Hardware Accelerator or OpenGLRender? I did try disabling Hardware Accelerator, but Same issue as it won't fill the polygon correctly.

Comment: In PathOverlay, there is one optimization (lines 242-247) assuming that the path is not to be filled, and which causes those issues with filled polygons. This optimization has been removed in the Polygon class. So, yes, the OSMBonusPack Polygon fills correctly (this was the main goal for introducing this class).

Comment: When `clearTileCache()` is called this is suppose to reduce total memory allocated right?

Answer (score 0):

A "great circle" on a map represents the shortest "as the crow flies" path between two points. It is going to look like a straight line on your map. You need to think of the Earth as a sphere when considering the centre of the great circle; the centre is of course, the centre of the Earth.

Comment: I'm currently using PathOverlay to draw a circle/sector by adding various points manually calcuated from start and end points. Is there a better approach provided by the API, that would help me draw a sector?

Comment: Another case is that my PathOverlay breaks the path if the points goes out of screen how, can I make it static or fixed?